# Recording java applet in loadrunner

Tags: java, applet, heap-memory, loadrunner, recording

I am trying to record a java applet in loadrunner . I have tried all the java  and web protocols , its giving me the error "Could not create Java Virtual machine " while recording although the script is working fine manually .Increasing the heap size also doesn't help.

When i tried with proxy recording nothing is getting captured .

Using winsock I am able to get a script ,but i am unable to parametrize it as i have no idea about socket scripting .

Is winsock my only chance to record  the applet ?

The applet is in java7 and i have loadruner 11.52 and the os is widows 7

Comment: This is a cross post from SQAForums for the same question: http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-mercury-loadrunner/150337-recording-java-applet-loadrunner.html Please choose which thread should be authoritative for answers, here or SQAForums. Shotgun posts across forums are counterproductive for finding solutions to questions. I would recommend you pick one forum, exhaust your answers there and then move onto another forum with the increased information from the first location.